# Subset df between two strings values - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with multiple values in varying order. I want to return all rows between two specific strings. The number of rows between these strings will vary so I need something robust. If one string doesn't follow the other then I want to drop all rows too.

Using below, I want to return all rows between `Green` and `Red`. This works fine if I get those strings in order. However, if `Red` doesn't appear before the next `Green`, I want to drop all rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['Green', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Purple', 'Brown', 'Green','Purple', 'Red'],
              'rating': [3, 4, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
              })

idx_start = df.index[df.Color == 'Green']
idx_end = df.index[df.Color == 'Red']

# seqeunce
seq = list(zip(list(idx_start), list(idx_end)))

# unpack list of list
g2 = [list(range(x[0], x[1] +1)) for x in seq]

# subset
df = df.iloc[np.r_[[y for x in g2 for y in x]]]
```

out:

```
     Color  rating
0    Green     3.0
1     Blue     4.0
2      Red     5.0
5    Green     NaN # No Red before next Green. Remove
6     Blue     3.0 # No Red before next Green. Remove
7   Purple     4.0 # No Red before next Green. Remove
8    Brown     5.0 # No Red before next Green. Remove
9    Green     6.0
10  Purple     7.0
11   Brown     8.0
12     Red     9.0
```

intended df:

```
     Color  rating
0    Green     3.0
1     Blue     4.0
2      Red     5.0
9    Green     6.0
10  Purple     7.0
11   Brown     8.0
12     Red     9.0
```

Comment: I'm probably off by 1 on some of this, but you can try writing a loop https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17zhVHxR9U05RYnPtqPOOZpk7_-6_T0j6#scrollTo=hDp1OVvA6LOf  (check out this notebook). There may be a more elegant vectorized solution, or some CS driven graph based algorithm you can use, but this seems simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `transform` with `groupby` with `cumsum`

```
g = df.Color.eq('Red').groupby(df.Color.eq('Green').cumsum())
cond1 = g.transform('sum')>=1
cond2 = g.transform('idxmax')
out = df[cond1 & (df.index<=cond2)]
out
Out[28]: 
     Color  rating
0    Green     3.0
1     Blue     4.0
2    Brown     5.0
3      Red     NaN
8    Green     5.0
9   Purple     6.0
10     Red     7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
color = np.array(df['Color'])
rating = np.array(df['rating'])

res = []
got_green = 0
got_red = 0
for i, j in zip(color, rating):
    
    if (not np.isnan(j)):
        # Start from green
        if (not got_green and not got_red):
            if i=='Green':
                got_green = 1
                got_red = 0
                res.append(True)

        # From Green to next not nan Red
        elif (got_green and not got_red):
            if i=='Red':
                got_red = 1
                got_green = 0
            res.append(True)

        # From red to next green
        elif (got_red and not got_green):
            if i=='Green':
                got_red = 0
                got_green = 1
                res.append(True)
            else:
                res.append(False)
        
    else:
        res.append(False)

df['to_select'] = res
df = df[df['to_select'] == True]
df
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['Green', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Purple', 'Brown', 'Green','Purple', 'Red'],
              'rating': [3, 4, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
              })

idx_start = df.index[df.Color == 'Green'].to_list()
idx_end = df.index[df.Color == 'Red'].to_list()

# create valid set
valid_index = []
end_list_index_pointer = 0
for idx_s, val in enumerate(idx_start):
    if idx_s == len(idx_start)-1 and val < idx_end[end_list_index_pointer]: 
        valid_index += list(range(val,idx_end[end_list_index_pointer] + 1))
        end_list_index_pointer +=1
    elif val < idx_end[end_list_index_pointer] < idx_start[idx_s + 1]:
        valid_index += list(range(val,idx_end[end_list_index_pointer] + 1))
        end_list_index_pointer +=1
    else:
        continue


print(df)
print()
print(df.iloc[valid_index])
```

**Result:**

[image]